# Homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ and $S^n\times\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

How to establish a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ and $S^n\times\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Thomas and Git both give ways of doing this for $n=1$. This is probably the most important step for solving the problem. However the second part of solving it is generalizing what you know about $n=1$ to $n > 1$. For $n > 1$, you can still define a radius and this is what is sent to the $\mathbb{R}$ component (with a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$). It should then also be clear what you need to send to $S^n$. What might not be clear is that this is a homeomorphism. For this, write down everything in coordinates and you will be able to see that the maps are continuous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R} \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269712/finding-a-homeomorphism-mathbbr-times-s1-to-mathbbr2-setminus-0-0)

Comment: this question is broader, however

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Consider $n=1$ and polar coordinates.

Comment: [Further help](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269712/finding-a-homeomorphism-mathbbr-times-s1-to-mathbbr2-setminus-0-0?rq=1).

Answer (score 7):

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\} \to S^n \times \mathbb{R}_{++}$ given by $$f(x):=(x/||x||,||x||).$$ It's a homeomorphism, you just need to compose it with a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}_{++}\to \mathbb{R}$.